# Convert string representation of list to list in clojure

Tags: clojure

If I have

```
(def a "((a,"a1",0.533,0.122,0.608,0.258) 
         (c,"c1",0.863,0.031,0.998,0.667) 
         (b,"b1",0.53,0.117,0.609,0.256))")
```

I would like to have

```
(def b '((a,"a1",0.533,0.122,0.608,0.258) 
         (c,"c1",0.863,0.031,0.998,0.667) 
         (b,"b1",0.53,0.117,0.609,0.256)))
```

where I can access each element in b with

```
(first b) ; which should return (a,"a1",0.533,0.122,0.608,0.258)
```

and

```
(type (first (first b)) ; returns clojure.lang.Symbol
(type (second (first b)) ; returns java.lang.String
(type (last (first b)) ; returns java.lang.Double
```

I tried just putting `(symbol a)` but that seems to turn the entire string into a single symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is `clojure.edn/read-string`:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string
       "((a,\"a1\",0.533,0.122,0.608,0.258) (c,\"c1\",0.863,0.031,0.998,0.667)(b,\"b1\",0.53,0.117,0.609,0.256))")

;;=> ((a "a1" 0.533 0.122 0.608 0.258)
;;    (c "c1" 0.863 0.031 0.998 0.667)
;;    (b "b1" 0.53 0.117 0.609 0.256))

user> (def b (clojure.edn/read-string
               "((a,\"a1\",0.533,0.122,0.608,0.258) (c,\"c1\",0.863,0.031,0.998,0.667) (b,\"b1\",0.53,0.117,0.609,0.256))"))
#'user/b

user> (first b)
;;=> (a "a1" 0.533 0.122 0.608 0.258)

user> (type (first (first b)))
;;=> clojure.lang.Symbol

user> (type (last (first b)))
;;=> java.lang.Double

user> (type (second (first b)))
;;=> java.lang.String
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!